# Are these formal formulas equivalent?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

My textbook gave the following

$ \forall x_0 (\exists x_1 \ x_0=(\mathbf{O''} \cdot x_1) \vee \exists x_1 \ x_0=((\mathbf{O''} \cdot x_1)+\mathbf{O'}))  $,

then commented on the syntax and why the brackets are so important here, etc...

However, for this example, I gave

$ \forall x_0 \ \exists x_1 (\ x_0=(\mathbf{O''} \cdot x_1) \vee x_0=(\mathbf{O''} \cdot x_1)+\mathbf{O'}) $.

To me these are equivalent, but my text didn't mention this form and didn't necessarily suggest it's equivalent to the first.

So are they equivalent or the way I'm using $ \ \exists x_1 $  gives my formula a different meaning?

Thanks

---

**Edit**

In other words, can the existential quantifier be "factored" like I did?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The claim that either there is some object that is $P$ or there is some object that is $Q$, $\exists x_1 P(x_1) \lor \exists x_1 Q(x_1)$, is logically equivalent to the claim that there is some object that is either $P$ or $Q$, $\exists x_1 (P(x_1) \lor Q(x_1))$:

$\exists x_1 P(x_1) \lor \exists x_1 Q(x_1) \iff \exists x_1 (P(x_1) \lor Q(x_1))$.

---

Notice the same is **not** true for existential quantification with conjunction. For example, there exists a cat and there exists a dog, $\exists x \text{Cat}(x) \land \exists x \text{Dog}(x)$, but this does not exactly mean there exists something which is both a cat and a dog, $\exists x (\text{Cat}(x) \land \text{Dog}(x))$.

[image]

As a caveat to the preceding image, it would be true to say that all objects are both a cat and a dog, $\forall x (\text{Cat}(x) \land \text{Dog}(x))$, if and only if all objects are a cat and all objects are a dog, $\forall x \text{Cat}(x) \land \forall x \text{Dog}(x).$

Comment: One fine day with a woof and a purr

Answer (score 10):

[The existential quantifier distributes over disjunction](https://cse.buffalo.edu/~rapaport/191/distqfroverandor.html). So the two sentences are indeed logically equivalent.

Comment: Great article, thanks.